# NullPointerException archetype:crawl

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I'm trying to discover the archtypes installed in my local repository. I read this is possible run the following command:

> mvn archetype:crawl

Now when I run this command I get this error:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:crawl (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:crawl failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:crawl (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:crawl failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:crawl failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.closeZipFile(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.isFileSetArchetype(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.repositorycrawler.DefaultRepositoryCrawler.crawl(DefaultRepositoryCrawler.java:72)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CrawlRepositoryMojo.execute(CrawlRepositoryMojo.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue. A null pointer with an "error in opening zip file" just before the build failure. I fixed it by deleting the file in question which was a jar that was corrupted in my local maven repository (Got an error when trying to open it with winrar).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known [bug](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-355) of older `maven-archetype-plugin` versions. Try specifying the last stable plugin version explicitly:

> mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:crawl

If the bug is still there, try checking file permissions in your local maven repository folder. There should be at least "read" permission on all jar files inside it.

If you run maven with the -X switch you will probably get the real cause of the problem in the console log just before the `BUILD FAILURE` message. Something like `[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.UnknownArchetype: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /path/to/file.jar (Access denied)`

Comment: @Skizzo Hmmm... It looks like that bug was not fixed properly. As a workaround try checking file permissions in your local maven repository folder. There should be at least "read" permission on all jar files inside it.

Comment: I run the command with the option -X and just before the BUILD FAILURE message i get the following message: [DEBUG] org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.UnknownArchetype: java.util.zip.Zip
Exception: error in opening zip file

Comment: @Skizzo I've found another issue that is very similar to yours: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-423. Unfortunately it is still unresolved...