# Maven can not find my custom maven archetype

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

### Unable to use a custom created maven archetype.

---

Maven tells me: Your filter doesn't match any archetype.
My system:

- Windows 7
- Java 7
- Maven 3.2

The steps I have taken are:

1. Create my project
2. Navigate to my project in command prompt and run the command:

   ```
   mvn archetype:create-from-project
   ```
3. Navigate to target\generated-sources\archetype and run this command:

   ```
   mvn install archetype:update-local-catalog
   ```
4. cd back to my Projects folder and run the command

   ```
   mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local
   ```

   Once I run that command I see:

   ```
   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
   [INFO]
   [INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleTreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
   [INFO]
   [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Building restTemplate-archetype 1.0-SNAPSHOT
   [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------
   [INFO]
   [INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) @restTemplate-archetype >>>
   [INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) @restTemplate-archetype <<< 
   [INFO]
   [INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) @restTemplate-archetype ---
   [INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
   [INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
   Choose archetype:
   Your filter doesn't match any archetype (hint: enter to return to initial list)
   choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): :
   ```

**However**
If I navigate in Eclipse to New->Project->Maven Project
I go to select an archetype, navigate to my archetype-catalog.xml (located in my ~/.m2/ directory) I see my archetype ready to be used... yet if I use my "default local" it's not there?

My settings.xml folder has my local repository set to

```
 <localRepository>~/Projects_3.7.1/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

If I attempt to use my archetype-catalog.xml, Eclipse will let me use my archetype... it breaks any XML, but that's something for another post. I believe if I let Maven generate my project from my custom archetype I'll be good.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run an additional `mvn archetype:crawl`.

I am not exactly sure why this is required. On my Mac system, `mvn install` does all requred steps, which also includes the `update-local-catalog` job. Running it from windows seems to result in the same problem you observed. Here an additional crawling of the repository seems to solve the problem. Depending on your maven version, look out for possible [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833438/nullpointerexception-archetypecrawl) with crawl.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.   One clue I can add:  After running `mvn install archetype:update-local-catalog` my **~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml** was updated.  But `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local` with a `-X` shows that the generate is looking for the catalog in  **~/.m2/repository/archetype-catalog.xml**.  Sure enough, `mvn archetype:crawl` writes the catalog to: **~/.m2/repository/archetype-catalog.xml**.  Now generate works, even if I delete the XML from **~/.m2** (as if I never ran `update-local-catalog` at all).   Wish I understood better.